# create view (subtract two different columns on different tables)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Can I create another view? subtract from **total_deposit - total_loan_amount**

```
CREATE VIEW v_total_deposit (total_deposit) as 
select sum(deposit_amount) 
from deposit;

CREATE VIEW v_total_loan (total_loan) as 
SELECT SUM(loan_amount) 
from loan;
```

Comment: Why not create one view that combine all three(if you really need a view for that) ?

Comment: @Nicholas Krasnov please give me example  instruction

Comment: @moonir01 - Would you like Nicholas to bring you the newspaper and a glass of lemonade, too? Where is your effort?

Comment: @mathguy i was try `CREATE VIEW balance (balance) as
SELECT TOTAL_DEPOSIT  FROM V_TOTAL_DEPOSIT
MINUS
SELECT TOTAL_LOAN FROM V_TOTAL_LOAN ;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@moonir01 [MINUS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries004.htm) is a set operator, not arithmetic one. You have to subtract two numbers:

```
CREATE VIEW balance
AS
   SELECT NVL((SELECT TOTAL_DEPOSIT FROM V_TOTAL_DEPOSIT),0) - NVL((SELECT TOTAL_LOAN FROM V_TOTAL_LOAN),0) AS balance
     FROM DUAL
```

but you really don't need these views.

Comment: Correct Answer ! thanks,  i need because my project all working procedure back end  work